# How to avoid duplicates in a 2d array when using push() method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple code that receives a 2d array (delivery report obtained from Google Sheets using getValues) as input, counts items based on certain conditions and pushes these counts to another array.

Each element in the 2d input array (delivery report) is comprised of vendorID with information about two possible types of delivered items. Each item delivered is a separate element (separate line on the report), even for the same vendor ID.

vendorID1 - item - item info
vendorID1 - item - item info
vendorID1 - item - item info
vendorID2 - item - item info
vendorID2 - item - item info
...and so on.

My code works by reading the first vendorID from the report (array[0][0]) with the outer For loop, then iterate through the array looking for matching vendorIDs with the inner For loop - if Condition1 is met increment Item1 by 1, if Condition2 is met, increment Item2 by 1. Then push() [vendorID, Item1_count, Item2_count] into another array.

The problem I'm having is that each iteration of the outer loop ends up pushing multiple duplicate records into the final array, since there are almost always multiple entries for each vendor ID inside the input array (delivery report) that correspond to each item delivered.

What I need is to figure out a way to skip or ignore vendor IDs that have already been counted, to avoid pushing the same data into the final array.

Initially my code was pushing data into a 1d array and I was able to use indexOf to check if a vendor ID has already been pushed, but I changed the code to create a 2d array instead for better data organization and indexOf no longer works. I came up with another workaround, but I don't know if this is the best solution, since I'm new to coding.
My other solution was to create another array to hold vendor IDs that have already been counted and then use indexOf on that array to prevent pushing duplicate entries.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
// Iterate through the array to get first/next vendorID on the list

for (var i=0; i<delivery_data.length; i++) {

  // Assign vendorID from input array (delivery report) to a variable
  var vendor_id = delivery_data[i][0];

  // Declare a variable to eventually hold vendorID counted last
  var last_counted_vendor;

  // Set item counts to 0

  var item1_count = 0;
  var item2_count = 0;

  // Execute inner For loop only if 
  // vendorID is not the same as previous iteration
  if (vendor_id != last_counted_vendor) {

  // I think j=i works and avoids searching from the 
  // beginning of the array every singe time
    for (var j=i; j<delivery_data.length; j++) {

      // If vendorID matches and condition1 is met, increment item1
      if (vendor_id == delivery_data[j][0] && condition1) {
      item1_count++;
      }
      // If vendorID matches and condition2 is met, increment item2
      else if (vendor_id == delivery_data[j][0] && condition2) {
        item2_count++;
      }
    }

   // Assign vendorID just counted to a variable
   last_counted_vendor = vendor_id;
   // Push vendorID and item counts to the final array
   count_data.push([vendor_id,item1_count,item2_count]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code could probably be significantly simplified - it would help if you posted an example of your input (the `delivery_data`) and desired output

Comment: Thank you for your offer! I'm not sure I'll be able to share the exact data, but I'll see if I can come up with the closest alternative.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to have a `Set` of `vendor_id`s found so far, and to `continue` if the `vendor_id` found is already included in the `Set`:

```
const vendorIds = new Set();
for (var i=0; i<delivery_data.length; i++) {
  const vendor_id = delivery_data[i][0];
  if (vendorIds.has(vendor_id)) continue;
  vendorIds.add(vendor_id);
  // etc
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Set(), but from a quick search it seems to be similar to an idea I had of using an array to hold vendor_id's already counted. How is it different from an array and what would be the advantage of using it instead of the script in its current form? Thank you!

Comment: An array is an *ordered* collection, while a `Set` is just a collection. Because you don't care about the order, only whether an item exists in the `Set` or not, it's probably more appropriate to use than an array. Another difference is that a `Set` can only contain unique elements: if you add two duplicate items to a `Set`, if you examine the `Set` later, you will only see one (unique) element. See MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looping through your array twice unnecessarily. A typical way to count elements is to create a hash map that holds your counts keyed to some ID.

In other words you would build an object that looks like:

```
map = { 
       id1: [id, count1, count2],
       id2: [id, count1, count2]
      }
```

Then as you loop through if `map` doesn't have a particular key it's the first time you've seen it and you add an array and increment. If it does exist, you just increment what you want.

Here's an example with some fake data where the condition is just whether `item info[1]` or `item info[2]` is set. At the end `Object.values` can return a plain array of your counts:

```js
// fake data
let delivery_data = [
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [2, 1, 0],
    [2, 1, 0],
    [2, 1, 0],
    [2, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [2, 1, 0]
]

//hash map
let map = {}

for (var i=0; i < delivery_data.length; i++) {
    let vendor_id = delivery_data[i][0];

    // id this id doesn't aleady exist the map, add it
    if (!map.hasOwnProperty(vendor_id)) map[vendor_id] = [vendor_id, 0, 0]

    // just process your count logic
    let current = map[vendor_id]
    if ( delivery_data[i][1]) {
        current[1] ++;
    } else if ( delivery_data[i][2]) {
        current[2] ++;
    }
  }

// the map looks like: 
console.log(map)
// if you just want the arrays of [id, count1, count2]
console.log(Object.values(map))
```

This makes your algorithm run in linear time rather than polynomial time, which in almost all cases will be faster.

Comment: Thank you for this! You are correct, I'm pretty sure my code is iterating through the array more times than necessary.
I've looked into hash mapping briefly, but that topic seemed to be beyond my current skill level, so I went with a more rudimentary approach. I'm going to study your example code and will try to apply it in my project(s) once I am more comfortable with objects.